# Adding two cosine waves, result in the standard A*cos(ωt + B) form

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

Let's say I have the composite wave:

$y(t) = \cos(40t) - 0.3 \cos(40t - 16)$

This combines two waves of the same frequency but different phases, and the objective here is to add them and present the result in the simplified form, as a single real amplitude multiplied by a single cosine. I have tried complex analysis, via $\operatorname{Re}[e^{i40t}(1-0.3e^{-i16})]$, but I still can't get a result out of it. May I ask what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your working is fine until

$\Re[e^{j40t}[1-0.3e^{-j16}]]$ now, remove time varying part ( harmonic part) and focus on it's phasor and write it in Euler form as i.e, $[1-0.3e^{-j16}]=1.28-0.0863j=1.282\ e^{-j0.0673}$

since wave is nothing but $=$ Re part of  $[\ \ \text{phasor}$$\times$ $e^{j\omega t}]$

so, your wave is $1.282 \cos(\omega t-0.0673)$ in your case phasor is rotating with frequency 40 radian per second in Anti clock wise direction i.e,put  $\omega=40$

Comment: Yeah, plus the fact that you calculate the absolute value with the square root of Re^2 + Im^2, and the argument of the exponential with the arctangent of Im/Re - both things that the guy from the other answer directly mentioned. 

Using complex numbers always simplifies it, so I'm picking your answer as the most straightforward one.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos{(40t)}-0.3\cos{(40t-16)}$$
$$=\cos{(40t)}-0.3\cos{(16)}\cos{(40t)}-0.3\sin{(16)}\sin{(40t)}$$
$$=(1-0.3\cos{(16)})\cos{(40t)}-0.3\sin{(16)}\sin{(40t)}$$
Now we want the above expression in the form
$$R \cos{(40t+\alpha)}=R\cos{(\alpha)}\cos{(40t)}-R\sin{(\alpha)}\sin{(40t)}$$
So, equating coefficients of $\cos{(40t)}$ and $\sin{(40t)}$ we have
$$R\cos{(\alpha)}=1-0.3\cos{(16)}$$
$$R\sin{(\alpha)}=0.3\sin{(16)}$$
Which we can solve simultaneously to give
$$R=\sqrt{(1-0.3\cos{(16)})^2+(0.3\sin{(16)})^2}$$
$$\alpha=\arctan{\bigg(\frac{0.3\sin{(16)}}{1-0.3\cos{(16)}}\bigg)}$$
So, the answer is
$$\cos{(40t)}-0.3\cos{(40t-16)}$$
$$=\sqrt{(1-0.3\cos{(16)})^2+(0.3\sin{(16)})^2} \times\cos{\bigg(40t+\arctan{\bigg(\frac{0.3\sin{(16)}}{1-0.3\cos{(16)}}\bigg)}\bigg)}$$
$$\approx 1.290192113\cos{(40t-0.06699439337)}$$